# Rhel7 hangs at "A start job running for read and set NIS domainname

Tags: rhel

I upgraded red hat 7.4 to 7.5. now it can't boot.Boot stuck at start job running for read and set NIS domainname from /etc/sysconfig/network (10 hour/ No limit).

Can anyone help?

Comment: if you're paying for RHEL7 they should have commercial support for that...

Comment: No i only have the developer license

Comment: I did notice some NISPLUS related changes to /etc/nsswitch.conf in the 7.5 update but I don't run NIS so can't say if those are related to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Enter single-user mode to clear the configuration in the /etc/sysconf/network file, then reboot the system.